# What is the difference between "enim" and "quia"?

Tags: word-comparison, conjunction

Consider the following two phrases:

> *noli timere: exaudivit **enim** Deus vocem pueri de loco in quo est* ([Genesis 21:17b](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+21&version=VULGATE))
>
> *et benedicentur in semine tuo omnes gentes terrae, **quia** obedisti voci meae* ([Genesis 22:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+22&version=VULGATE))

As I understand them, both are used in the sense of "for/because", but *quia* normally appears at the beginning of a sentence, whereas *enim* appears second in the sentence. Is this the only relevant difference, when it comes to the for/because meaning? (They have other meanings too, but my question is not about them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their semantic role is similar, but the syntactical one is not exactly.
I would say that *quia* is a conjunction, *enim* a particle.
In L&S [*quia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=quia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is indeed called a conjunction, and [*enim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=enim&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) a "demonstrative corroborative particle".
Reading the two dictionary entries will shed some light on their use.

The word *quia* corresponds to "because" quite accurately.
The word *enim* is more nuanced.
It can be used to strengthen many assertions, similarly to *vero*.
In addition to "because" or "for", it can stand for "certainly", "indeed", "in fact" and other.
You can also use *enimvero*, which is stronger than *enim* or *vero* alone.

The clause introduced by *quia* is a subordinate one and cannot stand independently.
The particle *enim* does not have this restriction.

To condense the comparison to a single sentence, I would say that *quia* is a subordinating conjunction that gives a reason and *enim* is a coordinating particle that gives emphasis and reason.

Comment: I'd say a parallel—though imperfect—in Spanish can be made: quia-porque/enim-pues @Anonym

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer: *enim* provides an explanation of the immediately preceding clause to the addressee; whereas *quia* states the actual reason why what has been said happened or is the case. *Enim* signalizes an epistemic cue, *quia* describes a causal connexion or reasons of the acting persons.